# How to save gforth image from inside interpreter

Tags: gforth

After one creates words in the interpreter, how does one save the image before issuing "bye"?

I have tried 'gforthmi test.fi' and 'gforthhmi test.fi test.asm'.

I am using the following as documentation:
https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~steve/CW/428/PBL%20Pages/gforth.pdf
also,
'Starting Forth' and 'Thinking Forth'.

The version of gforth is 0.7.3, recompiled from source on MacOS.